# Wild bunny - is she nursing or sick?

Tags: behavior, rabbits, breeding

In my backyard, there’s this wild bunny that has been sitting in the exact spot for 3 days now. I go out, she’s just sitting down looking at me. I’ve even gotten as close as 5 feet (150 cm) from her and she just stares at me. I’ve seen this one before and she runs off when I step outside.

I find this very peculiar and not sure what’s wrong with her. My wife says that nursing bunnies do that. I’m not sure if that is correct or not. So here are my questions:

1. Is this normal and is she nursing? Or should I call someone to come check on her?
2. If she is indeed nursing, is there anything I can do to help her out? We have a 6’ (180 cm) rat snake somewhere in our yard, a ~30 pound (~14 kg) possum, and a raccoon. I don’t want any of these other animals to hurt the bunny babies. Could I prevent this from happening or should I let nature run its course? Should I bring her water or food so she can eat and go back to her babies quickly?
3. If she is nursing, should I stay away from her? She’s right next to my vegetable garden and I would need to go in there soon. Is that safe for me? Is it ok with her? Or should I just keep my distance for her and my safety?

I understand this isn’t a pet of mine, but people do have bunnies as pets and I love all the little animals (except the snake, I hate that thing) in my backyard. So I figured it might be a good spot for this question.

Here’s a photo of her, if you’re curious:

[image]

Update:

She’s not stuck or nursing. She’s just lazy and bold. She’s been moving around near us and eating the dandelions and destroying my vegetable garden. Here’s a pic:

[image]

Comment: What happens, if you go closer? Will it move away? For me the picture offers the possibility, that it is trapped in some kind of way, maybe in the wire? In general it is a good way, to be interested in the wellbeing of all creatures ;)

Comment: @Allerleirauh I’ve gotten very close to her and she doesn’t even try to run. Usually in my experience, if an animal is trapped and you approach it, it tries to run. This one doesn’t.

Comment: Do you know, if rabies is an issue in your area? Please do not touch a apparently friendly wild animal without propper protection!

Comment: @Allerleirauh I very much do not intend on touching the rabbit or going too close to it, but from what I know, small rodents like rabbits are very unlikely to have rabies. Nevertheless, if I get bit by this one, I’ll be getting a shot for rabies. That disease scares me!

Comment: I have no experience with nursing rabbits, and sadly no time dor research :( But I would assume, that nursing rabbits would choose a more protected place for do so. An additional important fact: is it a european rabbit or a cottontail? Cottontails are not common in my area, but european would have burrows to raise their children.

Comment: I am not sure what kind this is, but this is in South-east USA. Maybe that would tell something about what kind of bunny this would be? My wife thinks that the bunnies in this region do make burrows for their children and that they like to sit on the babies till they grow fur and can roam freely. We've had some temperature drops in the past week too, so I am inclined to believe her. But I want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Another option could be, it is a lodt pet rabbit of another owner. Maybe used to humans, or overwhelmed because the first time in the nature... Have you noticed if it eats something? If european rabbits (cottontails are no pets) do not eat in 24 hours they get heavy problems with digesting and get high risk to die.  I am sorry, that I can not provide more help. Maybe you should have a look, if it is there in the night too. You could call some rescue organization and ask for advice. They will know the most common options of illness/nursing/trapped in your area and can provide instruction :)

Comment: Hi thanks for updating; SE permits answering own questions, so if you want, then you are welcome to include some more details about this rabbit (maybe one or two paragraphs about how you found out she is just lazy and bold, etc.) and post it with the new photo as an answer and we could reward you with reputation.

Comment: "lazy and bold" quite the combination.

Answer (score -2):

I would say the bunny is nursing however this is a guess. I would say call a vet/animal control and describe it to them and see what they say. However if you feel like its the best choice, then take it to the vet for a check up.

Comment: Hi Joseph Casey! You're new here. I can't help but notice your huge bursts of answers today. Please remember to leave *good-quality* answers, you shouldn't answer questions in 5 minutes. For example, "guesses" are usually **not tolerated** on SE Sites. Feel free to improve your answers or some may be removed.